# explain kvm_userspace_memory_region structure?

Tags: linux

In the link [KVM api](https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/) I can across the below structure in assigning memory to the guest.

```
struct kvm_userspace_memory_region region = {
    .slot = 0,
    .guest_phys_addr = 0x1000,
    .memory_size = 0x1000,
    .userspace_addr = (uint64_t)mem,
    };
    ioctl(vmfd, KVM_SET_USER_MEMORY_REGION, &region);
```

Yes, the above link explained each variable but it is hard for me to understand. The below is my understanding so far, kindly correct me if anything I misunderstand.

- Guest physical memory is also a virtual memory but it looks like a physical memory to the guest.
- Userspace address is the address that the user code's starting memory address.

Below is my doubts

- What is the purpose of the slot, can I assume it as it is similar to actual memory physical slot that we can see if we open the CPU.
- Is there any max memory limit to a single slot, If not what is the use-case of having multiple slots.
- Is memory size denotes the size of the userspace code or the size we are requesting for a guest physical address?
- Why in that example guest physical memory is starting from 4094 (0x1000) why it is not started from 0. If there is any memory layout or procedure, kindly explain or provide a working link, I will go through that link.

Comment: Why did you re-purpose your previous question, instead of keeping [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/566548/86440)?

Comment: @StephenKitt in my previous question no one added any comment or answer so it though modifying that question will not harm anyone. Also i will get a benifit of adding question in bounty. WDYT?

Comment: You could have added the bounty to your existing question. I was working on answering the previous incarnation of this question (about PTE structure)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the slot, can I assume it as it is similar to actual memory physical slot that we can see if we open the CPU.

It’s one memory mapping. There’s no relationship to physical memory slots.

> Is there any max memory limit to a single slot, if not what is the use-case of having multiple slots.

There is no limit apart from what’s available to the host. Multiple slots are useful because each memory “slot” in KVM can have different properties; currently, the mapping associated with a slot can be as-is (transparent), or log writes to it, or be read-only.

In addition, memory slots mapped in this way are intended for “physical” memory from the guest’s perspective; address space for memory-mapped I/O isn’t mapped to a memory slot. This means that a typical address space with discontiguous physical memory and interleaved MMIO areas needs multiple slots to be represented.

> Is memory size denotes the size of the userspace code or the size we are requesting for a guest physical address?

It’s the size of the memory mapping: `memory_size` bytes are mapped into the guest memory, starting at physical address `guest_phys_addr` (from the guest’s perspective), using memory at linear address `userspace_addr` (from the host’s perspective).

> Why in that example guest physical memory is starting from 4094 (0x1000) why it is not started from 0. If there is any memory layout or procedure, kindly explain or provide a working link, I will go through that link.

This is explained in the example:

> For our initial state, we will preload this code into the second page of guest "physical" memory (to avoid conflicting with a non-existent [real-mode interrupt descriptor table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table) at address 0).

Comment: Tnx @StephenKitt, will guest use "userspace_addr" like a main memory (RAM) or it is just to map user code to the guest?

Comment: The guest doesn’t use `userspace_addr`; that has meaning only in the host.

Comment: we are mapping outer process userspace_addr with guest's physical address right? If not what is the use of userspace_addr in the kvm_userspace_memory_region structure?
I was looking the image in the link https://events.static.linuxfound.org/slides/2011/linuxcon-japan/lcj2011_guangrong.pdf under title "GFN to PFN in KVM"

Comment: I thought if we write anything into a guest physical address (from a process inside guest) it will reflect in "userspace_addr (address we passed)", am i missing anything?

Comment: I thought that you meant that the guest would use the value in `userspace_addr`. Your last two comments are correct: the memory is mapped at `guest_phys_addr` in the guest, and reads and writes there from the guest read and write the memory mapped at `userspace_addr` in the host. (The accesses aren’t “reflected”, they’re mapped directly.)

Comment: tnx @StephenKitt let's take scenorio, I have process (p1) inside a guest and that p1 tries to write a value in memory, so address translation will be p1 virtual address -> guest physical address (userspace_addr). Here my doubt is, Is p1 is using userspace_addr like a RAM (physical address)? I was not able to visualize how kernal inside guest is using userspace_addr like real RAM (wondering how frames, swapping related concept work inside guest).
kindly don't take wrong if my question looks silly, just now learning memory management of vm.

Comment: the purpose of "kvm_userspace_memory_region" process is to provide memory space to the guest right? like allocating RAM to a process. am I missing anything?

Comment: It’s not silly ;-). Inside the guest, it behaves as physical memory, yes. If the guest swaps, it would write to its storage, not memory. Everything that’s mapped using this KVM API is equivalent to physical memory inside the guest.

Comment: The API provides memory to the guest, yes, and it also maps it at specific areas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104263/discussion-between-karthik-nedunchezhiyan-and-stephen-kitt).